# When using the GARCH model, should you subtract the mean (if it's none-zero) from your observations?

Tags: mean, garch

My understanding is the squared observation is a proxy for variance in GARCH models.  If the data itself has a non-zero mean, does it make sense to transform the data beforehand by subtracting the mean from each point before hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a GARCH(1,1) model for a time series $x_t$ with conditional mean $\mu_t$ and conditional variance $\sigma_t^2$:

\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t+u_t, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d.(0,1).
\end{aligned}

The model includes a specification of the conditional mean and the conditional variance.

> My understanding is the squared observation is a proxy for variance in GARCH models.

Unless you explicitly assume the data to have zero mean, squared observations $x_t^2$ are not proxies for variance; squared model residuals $u_t^2$ are (you find them in the equation for $\sigma_t^2$).

> If the data itself has a non-zero mean, does it make sense to transform the data beforehand by subtracting the mean from each point before hand?

No, you do not need to do that. 
You do not need to preprocess the data to remove the mean since you can specify the mean equation within the model. In your case, it would be $\mu_t=\mu$ (a constant).

Comment: I guess I got confused because when we test to see if an ARCH model fits the data, we square the data and look at ACF plot and Ljung-Box test.  That's why I thought squared observation is a proxy for variance

Comment: @user6472523, even then, when testing for ARCH effects, conditional mean should be subtracted from the data. When testing the adequacy of a GARCH model, we examine the standardized residuals (fitted values of $\varepsilon_t$ above) and their squares. So in fact, we do not examine square data unless we are assuming the mean to be zero.

Comment: conditional mean would be the mean derived from an ARIMA model?  so we would never just square the data and test for ARCH effects, correct?

Comment: @user6472523, either an ARIMA model or a constant or some other model (say, with exogenous regressors). We would not square the data themselves unless we assume their conditional mean is zero. This could sometimes be assumed, e.g. for stock returns or the like.

Comment: ah that makes sense.  my class does tend to work with stock returns so that's why we square the data itself sometimes.  thank  you!

Comment: so absent of the mean equation (let's say you don't have one and thus don't have standardized residuals), you can still test for the ARCH effect by subtracting the mean from the original data and squaring the result, then doing a Ljung-Box test or ACF plot, correct?

Comment: @user6472523, in a GARCH model, you always have a conditional mean equation. It can be "empty" such as $x_t=u_t$ or very simple like $x_t=\mu+u_t$, but there always is one. By subtracting the mean as you mention you are effectively assuming $x_t=\mu+u_t$. But regardless of whether you think about equations or not, if you assume a constant mean, then subtracting it from the data and squaring the result gives you $u_t^2$ which can be used for Ljung-Box test or ACF plot.